# WM_CREATE doesn't seem to be processed in child window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a window `HWND assignWnd` that is a child window of the main window. This window doesn't seem to process the WM_CREATE message. For example, here is the WM_CREATE message within my window procedure.

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hdc = GetDC(assignWnd);

        GetTextMetrics(assignWnd,&tm);
        cyChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;

        ReleaseDC(assignWnd,hdc);
        return 0;
    }
```

The variable `cyChar` is an `int` and is declared within the window procedure. It is used later in the WM_PAINT message. Whenever I compile the program, I get a run-time error stating that `cyChar` is being used before it initialized. If I place the above code within the WM_PAINT message however, the program works as expected.

The obvious problem is that I don't want these calls  to be made every time the window is painted. I would like these commands (and others later on) to be processed during the WM_CREATE message.

Any explanation as to why the WM_CREATE message is not being processed in this child window  be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind. I found the problem was that "cyChar" was not declared static, therefore it wasn't valid for the other messages.

Comment: If this was part of your message processing loop, it wouldn't matter whether it was static or not since the code never leaves the loop. Static variables should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Mark, I declared it within the window procedure and before the switch(msg) used to process various messages. Also, out of curiosity, why do you recommend avoiding static variables?

Comment: It raises the scope of the variable beyond a single function call, especially if it's global. That makes it harder to reason through the workings of your code. If used judiciously it's not an insurmountable problem. For this particular use case it might not make any difference whatsoever, but it's still a good rule to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `cyChar` is local to the window procedure. It's not a question of `WM_CREATE` not being processed, it's that the `cyChar` you assign in `WM_CREATE` is not the same `cyChar` that you use in `WM_PAINT`. You need to make your variable global or static so that it survives from one call to the window procedure to another.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I realized this shortly after posting; however, due to my low reputation I was not able to answer my own question!